# Does $x^{2k} - x^k + 1$ divide $g(x)=x^{2n} + x^n + 1$ only when $n$ is even?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Let $n,k$ be positive integers. Suppose $f(x)=x^{2k} - x^k + 1$ divides $g(x)=x^{2n} + x^n + 1$. Can I conclude that $n$ is even by the following argument?

The roots of $f$ are the $k$th roots of the cube roots of -1 different from -1. Since $f$ divides $g$, these roots are also roots of $g$. The roots of $g$ are the $n$th roots of the cube roots of unity different from 1. Thus, if a root of $f$ is equal to a root of $g$,$$e^{\pm i\pi/3k} = e^{\pm 4\pi i/3n + 2\pi m i}$$ (where $m \in \mathbb{Z}$), and
$$\pm\frac{1}{3k} = \pm\frac{4}{3n} + 2m \implies \pm n = \pm 4k + 6mn,$$ so $n$ is even.

Comment: This seems correct! A simpler-to-write version of the same idea: since a root of $f$ is a $k$th root of a primitive $6$th root of unity, its multiplicative order thus equals $6d$ for some divisor $d$ of $k$—in particular, the order is even. Similarly a root of $g$ has order $3c$ for some divisor $c$ of $n$. If the roots of $f$ are also roots of $g$, then $c$ and therefore $n$ must be even. (Indeed, this shows that $n$ must be even if $f$ and $g$ simply have a nontrivial gcd.)